# Access Denied for Login

Tags: drupal, user-account

On a handover document from a fundraiser to a volunteer, this link was left to access our database. When it is clicked on it takes you to a page which says 'Access Denied'. Why is this? I'm assuming this database is not paid for and we don't owe money. We really need to access this quite urgently. We have record of the login and password. Any help would be greatly appreciated. How can you contact CIVI for help or is this the only way to get feedback? Thanks.

https://spires.civisites.com/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://spires.civisites.com/user and there you can log in.

By the way I would think you actually ARE paying for the hosting. The hosting company is civisites and you can try to contact them (https://www.civisites.com/about-us / http://www.circle-interactive.co.uk/)